# Iterative Union ALL's

Tags: sql, sql-server, iteration, union

I have a large SQL Server 2012 Database which I am querying 3 tables to create a result set of 5 fields.

I want to repeat this query in a WHILE - loop and "UNION ALL" the result sets obtained in each loop. This iteration will be on a variable: @this_date which will increment over the past 6 years and stop at today's date.

At each iteration a different results set will be obtained by the SELECT.

So I am trying to code the Stored Procedure as follows:

```
Declare @the_date as Date, 
        @to_date as Date 

-- I setup the above dates, @the_date being 6 years behind @to_date
--  Want to loop for each day over the 6-year period


WHILE (@the_date <= @to_date) 
BEGIN 

--  the basic select query looks like this

Select Table1.Field-1, Table2.Field-2 ...
FROM Table1
Inner Join  Table2 ...
On ( ..etc..  )

--  the JOIN conditions are based on table.attributes which are compared with 
-- @the_date to get a different result set each time

-- now move the date up by 1

DateAdd(Day, +1, @the_date)

-- want to concatenate the result sets

UNION ALL 
END
```

The above gives me a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Union'.

Any ideas on a solution to my problem would be welcome
- thanks.

Comment: Insert result from the loop into a table variaable and select from that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to get the records from `@this_date` and 6 years past it? If you can state your objective clearly, I may provide an answer that does not include any looping.

Comment: how does `@this_date` used in your query ?

Comment: You seem to have a profound misunderstanding of the difference between the scripting language (T-SQL) and the query language (SQL).  A clear description of what you want to do, along with sample data and desired results might enable someone to help come up with a workable solution.

Comment: Hi Felix - To explain further: My SELECT above will retrieve a different results set of 5 fields depending on the value in @this_date. These fields are varchar(30), integers/etc

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a UNION.  You can't in a loop anyway.  Instead store the results of each iteration in a temp table or a table variable and select from the temp table / table variable instead.

```
DECLARE @the_date as Date, 
        @to_date as Date

CREATE TABLE #t (Col1 VARCHAR(100))

WHILE (@the_date <= @to_date) 
BEGIN
   INSERT #t (Col1) SELECT ... etc
   DateAdd(Day, +1, @the_date)
END

SELECT Col1 FROM #t
```

That said, if you provide some sample data and expected results we might be able to help you with a more efficient set-based solution.  You should avoid iterative looping in RDBMS whenever possible.